# Windows Web Server 2008 workgroup?

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-server

I've only used Windows Server Web edition in the context of a domain, but now I have a situation where a computer needs to run Windows Web Server, but that server is not part of a domain.  I'm just curious and I can't find anything with a quick googling that confirms or denies for me whether Windows Server Web edition will work outside of a domain (in a workgroup), and I need to know for sure before placing the order.  Can anyone speak from experience here?

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. What exactly are worried about not functioning in a workgroup?

Comment: Well, I just meant the server in general.  In other words, does a windows web server 2008 machine *have* to be part of a domain?  I'm assuming from your comment that it probably doesn't but want to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason that Windows Server Web edition should need a domain to work. The web edition is just a version of Windows Server that has been stripped down to just what you need to run a web server (IIS, ASP.NET, etc.). Setting up a web server on the Web edition should be identical to installing IIS on any other edition of Windows Server. I can say from experience that you do *not* need a domain to install IIS and nothing else.